# HTML5 Video is not working when refreshing the browser

Tags: html, wordpress, video, mp4, webm

I have to create a website with a full-screen dragdealer.js slideshow, embedding in one of its slide a HTML5 video as background.

I'm using Wordpress & video-js.
So I hardcode in a WP post the following code :

```
<video height="450" width="800" poster="Absolute_poster_link" autoplay="autoplay" preload="metadata" loop="loop" class="video-js" id="bg_video" tabindex="0">
<source src="Absolute_mp4_link"  type="video/mp4"></source>
<source src="Absolute_webm_link" type="video/webm"></source>
<source src="Absolute_ogv_link"  type="video/ogg"></source>
</video>
```

When the page is triggered with a parent link the page is loading, displaying the video in background so it works but when I just press F5 or refreshing the browser (Firefox, Chrome...) on this page, the video is just black, anything is working...

Does anybody got a solution to this issue ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to make this work.
It seems like Wordpress is bad for posting HTML5 video tags with autoplay property in its posts areas. So I decided to create the HTML5 tag with a javascript function and the .append() jQuery method and it works for me !

I hardcoded something like that :

```
function appendVideo(){
    jQuery('#main').append('<div id="video-loop-wrapper"><div class="video-overlay "></div><div id="video-loop"></div></div>');
    jQuery('#video-loop').html('<video id="bg_video" width="800" height="450" loop="loop" preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" poster="poster_link"><source src="video_.mp4_link" type="video/mp4" /><source src="video_.webm_link" type="video/webm" /><source src="video_.ogv_link" type="video/ogg" /></video>');
    }
```